# Save user ID when registering with Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using toMap () to save the data inside the document in Firebase but I can't find a way to save the user id that was created during registration as well. So my code look like this:

```
_registerUser(User user) {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: user.email, password: user.password)
        .then((firebaseUser) {
      Firestore db = Firestore.instance;

      db.collection("users").document(firebaseUser.uid).setData(user.toMap());

      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
    }).catchError((error) {
      setState(() {
        _errorMessage =
            "Error";
      });
    });
  }
```

And this is my model user.dart

```
class User {
  String _name;
  String _username;
  String _email;
  String _password;

  User();

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      "username": this.username,
      "email": this.email,
      "name": this.name,
    };

    return map;
  }

  String get password => _password;

  set password(String value) {
    _password = value;
  }

  String get email => _email;

  set email(String value) {
    _email = value;
  }

  String get username => _username;

  set username(String value) {
    _username = value;
  }

  String get name => _name;

  set name(String value) {
    _name = value;
  }
}
```

How can I save the generated uid along with these other values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly Firebase has a `class User` defined.

Rename your class to something like `MyUser`.

```
class User {
  String _uid;//added a field to store uid
  String _name;
  String _username;
  String _email;
  String _password;
}
```

Register with email and password.

```
_registerUser(String email,String password) {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password:password)
        .then((firebaseUser) {
```

*Firebase gives a firebaseUser here.
You can get the uid. firebaseUser.uid
Set the uid,email,password,using the setters from your class into an obj eg. MyUser myUser;*

```
      Firestore db = Firestore.instance;


          db.collection("users").document(firebaseUser.uid).setData(myUser.toMap());

      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
    }).catchError((error) {
      setState(() {
        _errorMessage =
            "Error";
      });
    });
  }
```

Firebase gives you a uid here.

Answer (score 2):

you can get your id as below

```
 final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    User user = (await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password))
        .user;
```

here user object has yourId and you can proceed to save to firestore
in this case i'll use a json

```
class UserModel {
  String username;
  String email;
  String name;
  String userId;

  UserModel({this.username, this.email, this.name, this.userId});

  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    username = json['username'];
    email = json['email'];
    name = json['name'];
    userId = json['userId'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['username'] = this.username;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['userId'] = this.userId;
    return data;
  }
}
```

save to firebase

```
var user =UserModel(
email..
username..)..
```

finaly

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .doc("users/${user.userID}")
            .set(user.toJson());
```